# meteor public folder: how to log requests

Tags: meteor

Meteor default web proxy serves files contained in the public folder.
Is it possible to log public folder requests without using a third-party web proxy?

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can. There is a [`webapp`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/webapp) Meteor package which is included to every project by default.

Place this code somewhere on the server:

```
WebApp.connectHandlers.use('/', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('Someone requested file: ' + req.originalUrl);
    next();
});
```

**Note**: Keep in mind browser cache, so you won't see all the requests you expected.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work locally. I caught some requests using "/" instead of "/public" but not all. I will continue investigations around webapp package, thanks.

Comment: I wonder if `WebApp.connectHandlers.use` is not limited to routed urls (I use Iron Router)

Comment: @Bolo see my update answer. It has nothing to do with Iron Router.